# Java health checker best practise

Tags: java, spring, sftp, session-state

I'm using Spring Integration to load file to sftp. I have SessionFactory like:

```
<bean id="sftpSessionFactory" class="org.springframework.integration.sftp.session.DefaultSftpSessionFactory">
        <property name="host" value="${host}"/>
        <property name="port" value="${port}"/>
        <property name="user" value="${username}"/>
        <property name="password" value="${password}"/>
        <property name="knownHosts" value="${known.hosts}"/>
</bean>
```

I need to check every several hours if sftp is healthy. Is this the correct way to use the DefaultSftpSessionFactory in health checker?

```
public class HealthChecker
{
    @Autowired
    private DefaultSftpSessionFactory sftpSessionFactory;

    public String doHealthCheck()
    {
        try
        {
            SftpSession sftpSession = sftpSessionFactory.getSession();
            if (sftpSession.isOpen())
            {
                sftpSession.close();
                return "OK";
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            LOG.error("Can't connect to sftp", ex);
        }
        return "ERROR";
    }
}
```

Are there some best practices what we need to use when HealthCheck is used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the idea behind your solution is good, just keep in mind that health check services should not be heavy. Just in case if you use any monitoring tool, that does polling every N seconds/minutes, it might fail from time to time, if your health check service is long running.

I also would recommend to use Spring Actuator, something like that:

```
 @Endpoint(id = "sftp")
 @Component
 @RequiredArgsConstructor
 public class SftpEndpoint {
     @ReadOperation
     public Map<String, Object> sftp() {
     }
 }
```